# How I can get all values using javascript from html table, into array associative or something

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need each ID book, quantity and cost (inputs) and send them by post method ajax. But I don't know how to build an array for this.

I can put all id's and values into "hidden" inputs, but maybe there are better ways.

HTML:

```
<ul id="list-data">
<li class="first">Name Book #1</li><li class="quantity"><input style="border:none;" type="text" value="0"></li><li class="cost">3.6</li>
<li class="first">Name Book #2</li><li class="quantity">0</li><li class="cost">     <input style="border:none;" type="text" value="2.5"></li>
etc..
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="id-client" value="3" />
```

Like this:

array ('IDBOOK1' - quantity value - cost value,
('IDBOOK2' - quantity value - cost value
(ID-CLIENT = 3) 
or something.

Not jquery please.

Comment: You might be in over your head if this all you got in terms of trying to work out your own problem. But the general concept is; loop through the inputs and push the values into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var names = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
var costs = document.getElementsByClassName("cost");
var books = [];
for(var i=0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    name = names[0].innerText;
    quantity = quantities[0].value;
    cost = costs[0].innerText;
    books.push({name:name, quantity:quantity, cost:cost});
}

console.log(books);
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8c0cwxh7/4/